# Create a form example in Yii

Tags: yii

I've been struggling with creating a simple form that will later store data in the database, using Yii framework and none of the tutorials I have been following have been explanatory enough. The idea is that I am editing an existing Yii project and I need to add user registration functionality to the following project. So Gii is out of the option.

To my understanding I have created:

- User controller (controllers/UserController.php)
- User model (models/User.php)
- Register view (/views/register.php)

What is the general idea that I should follow in order to create a form in the view, and add data from that form on the database?

**On the controller so far I have:**

```
class UserController extends LSYii_Controller {


public function actionIndex() {  }}
```

The model:

```
public static function insertUser($new_user, $new_pass,$new_full_name,$parent_user,$new_email)
{
    $oUser = new self;
    $oUser->users_name = $new_user;
    $oUser->password = hash('sha256', $new_pass);
    $oUser->full_name = $new_full_name;
    $oUser->parent_id = $parent_user;
    $oUser->lang = 'auto';
    $oUser->email = $new_email;
    if ($oUser->save())
    {
        return $oUser->uid;

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and on the view I have nothing since I am not sure on how to proceed.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see you are new to Yii, try to follow the blog tutorial here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.overview Try to finish the whole tutorial, don't just copy the code but try to understand the general concept of it. this will take some time but it will be worth it in the end.

Comment: You should first read the [form section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview) from the guide.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about Yii is it's plugin architecture. There is a user registration and management module that will do all of this for you. It's free and available from:

http://yii-user.2mx.org/

Features:

- Login from User Name or Email
- Registration
- Activation accounts (verification email)
- Recovery password (send recovery key to user email)
- User profile page
- Manage Users
- Manage Profile Fields
- Profile field widget for view, edit and save data (FieldWidget)
- Date widget (jQueryUI datepicker)
- File upload widget
- Profile Relation Widget
- API

You can edit the User class to add other fields or store those additional fields in another table if you didn't want to mess with the yii-user code/configuration.